# VSCode: PHP executable not found even after setting env variable and pointing vscode to php.exe

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I installed the [PHP Intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-intellisense) extension and followed the instructions to point VSCode to my php file, I also setup the environmental; variable in windows to point to the php directory.

When I open VSCode I get the following error:

> PHP executable not found. You need PHP 7 installed and in your PATH

**VSCode Settings:**

[image]

**Environmental Variables:**

[image]

How can I get this to work?

I have referred to:

- ["Cannot validate the php file. The php program was not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34182067/cannot-validate-the-php-file-the-php-program-was-not-found)
- [PHP executable not found. Install PHP 7 and add it to your PATH or set the php.executablePath setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40287927/php-executable-not-found-install-php-7-and-add-it-to-your-path-or-set-the-php-e)

Comment: Did you try forward slashes in the VS executablePath like `"C://path.to.your.php.folder//php.exe"`?

Comment: @j08691 Yeah, same deal

Answer (score 1):

You need to click on "Path" and highlight it in the list of System variables and then click the Edit button.  A new window with a list of paths in the environmental variable will open.  Click the New button on the top right and type or paste your copied path to PHP.exe there.  It should work then.

Answer (score 1):

You have to **append** php path to the Path variable. 
Click on "Path" select edit
[image: click the red color marked item] 
**Do not modify the values**, just insert semicolon(**;**) to the end of the values, then paste(append) "C:\xampp\php" to end of the Path value
Then save settings. You may need to restart your machine

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue, I did exactly as your case but still got the error, the below solution worked for me.

I had changed the `.EXE` PHP file to: `php-win.exe` and that's it, the VS settings should like that (according to my path):

```
"php.validate.executablePath": "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\PHP\\php\\php-win.exe",
"php.executablePath": "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\PHP\\php\\php-win.exe"
```

[image: VS PHP Path]