# How to set php executable path php.validate.executablePath in vscode when php is set inside docker container?

Tags: php, docker, validation, visual-studio-code

I have a development environment based in docker.

Everytime that I open VSCode I get this message:

> Cannot validate since no PHP executable is set. Use the setting
>   'php.validate.executablePath' to configure the PHP executable.

Somebody know how to set php.validate.executablePath in this case?

I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/251

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/533

Comment: Yes!
All these links tell about PHP running local in your machine, and not about Docker Environments

Comment: Here is the answer with screenshots https://stackoverflow.com/a/36261014/4291272

Comment: Seems like all the answers on this page are saying...if you're working in Docker...install PHP on your machine anyway and set the path to it. Hopefully that clarifies the issue.

Comment: /usr/local/bin/php

Answer (score 66):

Here is a screenshot.

- Don't forget to escape `\`
- You don't have to add it to the Path

[image: set php.validate.executablePath snapshot]

Comment: @NgatiaFrankline  can i help you friend  ?  ,can you clarify  your question

Comment: @Elrashid sorry am late. Question is `How to set php executable path php.validate.executablePath in vscode when php is set inside docker container?
` My understanding is that docker runs containerized applications (like guest/virtual machine but with less resources. Readmore https://hub.docker.com/ ). Therefore it means you docker php environment (this can be Ubuntu) is different from your local desktop where vscode is installed (this can be windows). How to you get path to php.validate.executablePath of a guest/containerized OS from your local/development machine where vscode is installed???

Comment: @NgatiaFrankline the original question is "How to setting php.validate.executablePath?" on **2017** but It was changed **Sep 2019** [Click here to check the Revisions ](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43768614/revisions)

Comment: @Elrashid sure, my bad.

Comment: @NgatiaFrankline thank you for understanding ❤ , please feel free to tag me ,if you need help in any other question, thanks again for your attention and time ❤

Comment: Why is this being upvoted? It doesn't even attempt to answer the original question.

Comment: @Crasher the original question is "How to setting php.validate.executablePath?" on 2017 but It was changed Sep 2019 [Click here to check the Revisions ](stackoverflow.com/posts/43768614/revisions)

Answer (score 38):

In my case using XAMPP is like this

```
"php.validate.executablePath": "C:/xampp/php/php.exe"
```

hope that answer your question

Comment: on windows 10 it's got to be in yout path vars also. search for environment variables in the start menu and add it to the path. just the dir, not the exe. eg.: C:\php

Comment: Bingo. Exactly what I needed. Thanks

Comment: Straight answer, please pin this up

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Also depending on your installation you might have an additional folder between xampp and php.

Comment: XAMPP is not docker. While this answer is clearly useful to some, it does not answer the question.

Answer (score 34):

For linux users:
if you don't have PHP installed then first download,
 then in terminal type

`$ whereis php`

and it will show path for php executable (It will be either in `/usr/bin/php` or `usr/local/bin/php`) which you can copy from terminal.

In VScode goto `settings.json` file and paste

`php.validate.executablePath: /usr/bin/php`

Comment: Like other answers mention: don't forget to escape the slashes in path!

Comment: Upvote for the forgotten `whereis` command :D

Answer (score 15):

Sure, easy. Just follow what it's says.

**Go to File** > **Preferences** > **Settings** ... it will open the **settings.json** file.

add the following code:

```
{"php.validate.executablePath": "Here you put your PHP.exe path"}
```

You have to know where te `php.exe` file is in your computer, search in the `php/bin` folder.

Hope it works for you

Comment: But the PHP are inside a Docker Container not is my local machine

Comment: @Takashi neither of the answers above.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem but found the fix [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13356).

In Windows:

1. Go To System Properties
2. Go To Advanced Tab
3. Click "Environment Variables"
4. Select Path
5. Add a new path that points to your php 7 executable:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

My case, I'm using Laragon, so you should search where is your **php.exe**.

By **VSCode** just add.

```
"php.executablePath": "C:\\laragon\\bin\\php\\php-7.2.19-Win32-VC15-x64\\php.exe"
```

on **settings.json**.

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Download PHP, in my case, I downloaded from here:
http://windows.php.net/download/

Copy and paste the files to a location on your computer, and set the path:

"php.validate.executablePath": "C:/php/php.exe"

Comment: op specifically asked when the php runtime is inside a docker container, not how to install php in host machine and use it in vscode.

Answer (score 2):

`"php.validate.executablePath": "C:/php/php.exe"` wont work due to incorect escaping

try this;

```
"php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\php\\php.exe"
```

Answer (score 2):

I simply used double forward slashes and it worked, like so:

```
"php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe",
```

Answer (score 2):

VSCode
Linux Users:

Step 1:
In your terminal type

```
whereis php
```

In my case "php: /opt/lampp/bin/php"

Step 2:

```
{
  "php.validate.executablePath": "/opt/lampp/bin/php"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using VScode and have installed Php through MAMP, the default path should be:

```
C:/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.1/php.exe
```

`/` not `\`

Answer (score 2):

Unix / Linux / Mac / WSL ,

---

### Step 1 : Find PHP path

```
whereis php
```

Response will show you where your php directories are.

```
user@User:~$ whereis php

php: /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php8.0 /usr/bin/php8.1 /usr/lib/php /etc/php /usr/share/php8.0-opcache 
/usr/share/php8.0-xml /usr/share/php8.1-curl /usr/share/php8.1-opcache /usr/share/php8.0-gd 
/usr/share/php7.0-gd /usr/share/php7.0-common /usr/share/php8.0-readline /usr/share/php8.0-mysql 
/usr/share/php8.0-zip /usr/share/php8.1-mbstring /usr/share/php8.1-xml /usr/share/php8.0-mbstring 
/usr/share/php8.0-common /usr/share/php8.0-curl /usr/share/php8.1-readline /usr/share/php8.1-common 
/usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz
```

---

### Step 2 : Configure VS-Code

Go to -> "Preference -> Settings"
Search for -> "php path"
Then click -> "Edit in settings.json"

---

In my case I had multiple.
So I chose the one I wanted from the available versions and my VS-Code looked like this

---

```
"php.validate.executablePath": "/usr/bin/php8.1",
```

Answer (score 1):

If you get this on windows in VS code click on the blue 'open settings' button. Near the bottom of the screen this opens there's a link to enter the settings, click this to open the settings.json file. Edit the file to look like this:

```
{
    "php.executablePath" : "C:/php-7.4.2-nts-Win32-vc15-x64/php.exe",
    "php.validate.executablePath" : "C:/php-7.4.2-nts-Win32-vc15-x64/php.exe"
}
```

where C:/php-7.4.2-nts-Win32-vc15-x64 is the path to your PHP dir

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helps but I ran into the same problem with the extension PHP Intelephense in Visual Studio Code. What I did is read the instructions so the extension could work properly. So I disabled PHP Language Features by searching  "@builtin PHP" in the extensions. Also, other (3rd party) PHP extensions that provide similar functionality should also be disabled for best results. Finally, I added glob patterns for non-standard PHP file extensions to the files.associations setting. For example: "files.associations": { "*.module": "PHP" }

Doing this made the error go away. I'm new to PHP too, let me know if this is the correct way of solving this problem with PHP Intelephense.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the docker-specific revision of the question, I found this thread in the VS Code PHP Intellisense git repo issue that explains how to create a wrapper script. It will involve mapping volumes, though, so take that into account.

https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-intellisense/issues/150#issuecomment-330374124

Answer (score 1):

I have ubuntu and XAMPP.
The following worked for me.

Press CTRL + P
Type settings.json and hit ENTER.

Add the following line in settings.json

```
{
...
"php.validate.executablePath": "/opt/lampp/bin/php",
...
}
```

Make sure to proper syntax.

Answer (score 1):

For Wampserver:

Inside settings.json

```
"php.validate.executablePath": "C:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.4.26/php.exe"
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used such solution:

First, create a `php` file inside `/usr/local/bin/` and make it executable:

```
sudo touch /usr/local/bin/php
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/php
```

Update content of it with:

```
docker exec $(docker ps --filter name=-app --format '{{.ID}}') php "$@"
```

So this will find a container with the name `-app` at the end. I'm using it along with the docker compose where I have `php` inside some container which has `-app` at the end of the name. You can check more about `filter` [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#-filtering---filter).

And then update `php.validate.executablePath` with `/usr/local/bin/php`:

```
{
    "php.validate.executablePath": "/usr/local/bin/php"
}
```

Comment: Sounds like this is heading in the right direction but I get an error: `spawn Unknown system error -8`

Answer (score 1):

I am using Laragon and have 2 PHP versions PHP 7.4 and 8.1, so I configured my visual studio settings.json like this:

```
"php.validate.executablePath": [
    "D:/laragon/bin/php/php-7.4.33-Win32-vc15-x64/php.exe",
    "D:/laragon/bin/php/php-8.1.10-Win32-vs16-x64/php.exe"
],
```

Answer (score 0):

IF using Laragon...Dont forget to change \ to /

```
  "php.executablePath": "C:/laragon/bin/php/php-7.4.5-Win32-vc15-x64/php.exe",
```

Answer (score 0):

- Go to 'Preference' -> 'Settings'
- Search for> `php path`
- Then click `Edit in settings.json`
- Then just put your directory with (DOUBLE Backslash).

Here is an example of mine:

```
C:\\php\\php.exe
```

Here is the format:

```
drive:\\folder_name\\php.exe
```

This should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

php.validate.executablePath in laragon

In my case using laragon is like this

```
  "php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\laragon\\bin\\php\\php-7.4.19-Win32-vc15-x64\\php.exe"
```

- php-7.4.19-Win32-vc15-x64 : Note that this part of your file name may be different

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error. I have installed Laragon and this addition in setting.json worked for me.

> "php.executablePath":"C:/laragon/bin/php/php-7.2.19-Win32-VC15-x64/php.exe"

Answer (score 0):

"php.validate.executablePath": "C:\xamp\php\php.exe"
this is working for this case

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If php is inside a docker container and you don't need it or don't want to install it on you local system, you can create a php wrapper script like it is suggested here: https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-intellisense/issues/471

I prefer to use the remote container Microsoft extension on vscode and work inside the container itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the suggestions, but for me, I needed to add the path of the php.exe and php.ini file to the settings of fiveserver:
[see attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIuXq.png)

Basically, open settings in vs code, then go to **extensions > Five Server** and then look for **PHP:Executable** and **PHP:Ini**
Add the path of your php.exe and php.ini (they are in the same folder), and it should be good to go.

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to **settings.json** file in Visual Studio Code.
2. Copy this code into your json file:

```
"php.executables": {
    "v8.1": "C:\\xampp\\php"
 }
```

3. Now save it...

*Please remember that, the **"v8.1"** is the version of the php compiler.*

Answer (score -3):

I also got this error message. The path to `php.exe` was already set in my System Environment Variables.

The error went away when I commented out `"php.validate.executablePath": "c:/path/to/php7.2.10/php.exe"`, in the `settings.json` file in VSCode.