# bash: php: command not found in VSC only

Tags: php, bash, visual-studio-code

`php -v` works in individual terminals, but do not work in Visual Studio Code Terminal.

I tried `php -v` in Git Bash and Command Prompt in Windows, and all worked.

So I tried in VSC where I set default shell to Git Bash, but it shows error with `bash: php: command not found`
(I added php bin path to Path)

Terminal at VSC do not get PATH variable?

Comment: I think you may reference the answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1238410/running-php-works-in-command-prompt-but-not-git-bash)

Comment: Thank you for comment. I typed `alias php='c/php-7.3.10-Win32-VC15-x64'` and not working on VSC again. It seems problem is related to VSC. I can use php command at independent Git Bash, but fails in VSC.

Comment: Try to [hard code your PHP path in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43768614/how-to-set-php-executable-path-php-validate-executablepath-in-vscode-when-php-is/45240008#45240008).

Comment: Didn't work, too. It is obviously problem of VSCode. I just turned Bash on. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem... My problem was in VSC FlatPack version available in the Software Manager in Mint 18.3. I uninstalled it and got the original version on https://code.visualstudio.com See more at: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/44646