# PHP errors after reinstall wamp 3.2.3 and PHP 7.3

Tags: php, localhost, wamp, wampserver

I am facing 2 errors after Reinstalling WAMP 3.2.3 and PHP 7.3, the Errors are:

> Cannot validate since C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.3.21\php.exe is not a
> valid php executable. Use the setting 'php.validate.executablePath' to
> configure the PHP executable.

and

> PHP executable not found. Install PHP 7 and add it to your PATH or set
> the php.executablePath setting.

I also Set the Environmental Variables in system, and in VS Code I tried these:

```
{
"php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\wamp64\\bin\\php\\php7.3.21\\php.exe",
  "php.executablePath": "C:\\wamp64\\bin\\php\\php7.3.21\\php.exe"
} 
{
"php.validate.executablePath": "C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.3.21\php.exe",
  "php.executablePath": "C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.3.21\php.exe"
}
```

also, I Tried,

```
{
"php.validate.executablePath": "C:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.3.21/php.exe",
  "php.executablePath": "C:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.3.21/php.exe"
}
{
"php.validate.executablePath": "C://wamp64//bin//php//php7.3.21//php.exe",
  "php.executablePath": "C://wamp64//bin//php//php7.3.21//php.exe"
}
```

Please tell me the Solution.
Thank you

Comment: open the console and try the command "php -v" and watch if php.exe is in your path

Comment: yes ! I already check this.... the php version i am using is 7.3.21 and it shows the correct path..... i have tried all the trick which I saw in youtube videos and read it on google. but didn't work for me

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43768614/how-to-set-php-executable-path-php-validate-executablepath-in-vscode-when-php-is