# Setting PHP Executable Path in VS Code in Ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

**Version:**

- OS `lsb_release -a` : Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
- PHP Intelephense: 1.6.2
- PHP `php -v` : 8.0.1
- Laravel: 8.25

---

**Error:**

> Getting `Unexpected 'Unknown'`, `';' expected.`, `'VariableName' expected.` error.

These kind of lines are causing error

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers; //Unexpected 'Unknown' and ';' expected Error

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

Here, Screenshot of my error:

[image]

---

**Tried**

I've have added PHP executable path [VS Code article](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/php#_linux-and-macos). But still not working

`settings.json`

```
{
    "php.validate.executablePath": "/usr/bin/php"
}
```

`$ whereis php`

```
php: /usr/bin/php8.0 /usr/bin/php.default /usr/bin/php /usr/lib/php 
/etc/php /usr/share/php8.0-mysql /usr/share/php8.0-readline 
/usr/share/php8.0-common /usr/share/php8.0-zip /usr/share/php8.0-xml 
/usr/share/php8.0-bz2 /usr/share/php /usr/share/php7.1-common 
/usr/share/php8.0-opcache /usr/share/php8.0-mbstring /usr/share/php8.0-gd 
/usr/share/php7.1-mcrypt /usr/share/php8.0-curl /opt/lampp/bin/php 
/usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz
```

`$ which php`

```
/usr/bin/php
```

---

[Adding Backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52489156/14138027)

`settings.json`

```
{
    "php.validate.executablePath": "usr\\bin\\php"
}
```

Giving me following message

> Cannot validate since usr\bin\php is not a valid php executable. Use the setting 'php.validate.executablePath' to configure the PHP executable.

---

Thanks.

Comment: Is there some specific code causing this error?

Comment: Please revisit the question I've added error lines in my question.

Comment: Have you visited this question and the answers? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59149877

Comment: Yes. I did then only i said that i `Disable` Intelephense options.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved with this executable path to configure the PHP executable in VS Code:

```
    {
    "php.validate.executablePath": "/usr/bin/php8.1"
    }

    whereis php
    php: /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php8.1 /usr/lib/php /etc/php
       /usr/share/php /usr/share/php8.1-bcmath /usr/share/php8.1-xml /usr/share
    /php8.1-readline /usr/share/php8.1-zip /usr/share/php8.1-mysql /usr/share
    /php8.1-ldap /usr/share/php8.1-mbstring /usr/share/php8.1-common /usr/share
    /php8.1-intl /usr/share/php8.1-bz2 /usr/share/php8.1-gd /usr/share/php8.1-
    pgsql /usr/share/php8.1-curl /usr/share/php8.1-soap /usr/share/php8.1-opcache
     /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz
```

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code. Please go through the [Stack Overflow tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).