# Running composer install doesn't resolve undefined type error in cloned Laravel project

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I've cloned a Laravel project from Github, then I've run `composer install` for getting `vendor` folder. This folder has appeared but I also get weird red lines under each class that show `Undefined Type` errors. I also deleted the `composer.lock` and run `composer update`, but the errors are still there!
Is there any other thing that I should do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the version of laravel ?

Comment: @Aro It's version 9.11

Comment: @Aro I can also find the ```'Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations'``` file under the vendor folder but the error is still there.

Comment: Are you sure that you use it via namespace?

Comment: @Aro Yes, also it isn't just for one class,it's happening for all classes.

Comment: Are you sure that `composer install`  didn't throw an error?

Comment: Hm. It's very strange. Because I have installed project and I don't have problem with it. Maybe problem with IDE ?

Comment: @Aro It's the link of my project! https://github.com/hanieas/Expense-Mgmt-Backend
could you please check it out?

Comment: @Aro go to the ```src``` and run ```composer install```

Comment: @brombeer The project is running perfectly, but the errors still are there.

Answer (score 0):

The project was running perfectly, So I found out it was because of my IDE.
The VS Code wanted to validate code using php, and it is not finding php installed.
It's solved by setting `php.validate.executablePath` in Vs Code setting.
For more information: ["Cannot validate the php file. The php program was not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34182067/cannot-validate-the-php-file-the-php-program-was-not-found)